# How to hide the text from ComboBox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, .net-4.8

I want to have the dropdown from ComboBox and to bind SelectedItem, but don't want to show the selected item in the combobox. So, no matter what item is selected, I want to show only the arrow from the drop-down.
I always want to show this:
[image: I always want to show this:]

Can it be done without changing the viewmodels and the collection in the ItemsSource?

Comment: White text color maybe?

Comment: The background of the text is grey, and it may not be the same shade for all users, so I don't think that would solve my problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce the width, so it only fits the arrow:

```
<ComboBox Width="20">
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

[image]

Comment: It does solve my problem, although my magic number was 15 :) I think I will accept the solution, but I will wait for a little, just to see if there is a more elegant solution, because I am a little worried that for different users there could be a different size of the arrow...